# linq error: CS0102: The type already contains a definition

Tags: .net, asp.net, linq, mobile

I am working on a mobile.net project.
I am trying to make a list of restaurants which is displayed in a drop down list...whn d user selects an item he can add it to d list of favorites.
However I am getting an error

```
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0102: The type 'mobile_rest' already contains a definition for 'emptyChangingEventArgs'

Source Error:

Line 78: {
Line 79:    
Line 80:    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);
Line 81:    
Line 82:    private int _r_id;
```

I have no clue why this is happening...
is it because i used d same table in another file too?

Here is my code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Favorite.aspx.cs" Inherits="Favorite" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="mobile" Namespace="System.Web.UI.MobileControls" Assembly="System.Web.Mobile" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<body>
    <mobile:Form id="Form1" runat="server" BackColor="#fcf9f3" Method="get" Paginate="True">

        <mobile:Label ID="FaveError" Runat="server" ForeColor="red" 
            Font-Size="Small" Font-Bold="True" Visible="false" />

        <mobile:Label ID="Label2" Runat="server" ForeColor="#d3af63" Font-Italic="True" 
                Font-Name="Monotype Covasia" Font-Bold="True" text="Choose Favorite's" />

        <mobile:SelectionList ID="listSearch" Runat="server" DataTextfield="r_name"
                 DataValueField="r_name" BreakAfter="False">

        </mobile:SelectionList>

        <mobile:Command ID="btnadd" text="Add" Runat="server" OnClick="btn_add_Click" />

        <mobile:list runat="server" id="ListFavorite" DataTextfield="fave_name"
             DataValueField="user_id" Font-Size="Small" Font-Italic="True" 
             Wrapping="Wrap"  BreakAfter="True"/>
            <mobile:Command ID="btndelete" text="Delete" Runat="server" OnClick="btn_delete_Click" />

    </mobile:Form>
</body>
</html>
```

And code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mobile;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.MobileControls;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;

public partial class Favorite : System.Web.UI.MobileControls.MobilePage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["error_msg"] != null)
        {
            FaveError.Text = Session["error_msg"].ToString();
            Session["error_msg"] = null;
            FaveError.Visible = true;
        }

        //if (Session["user_id"] = null)
        //{
        //    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        //}
        GetRstr();
        GetFave();
    }

    protected void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid) // only valid page will proceed
        {
            AddFave();
        }
    }

    #region add fave
    protected void AddFave()
    {
        String faveitem = listSearch.SelectedIndex;

        using (FavoriteDataContext Favorite = new FavoriteDataContext())
        {
            mobile_favorite mobilefave = new mobile_favorite();
            mobilefave.fave_name = faveitem;
            mobilefave.user_id = Int32.Parse(Session["user_id"].ToString());
            mobilefave.username = Session["user_name"].ToString();

            Favorite.mobile_favorites.InsertOnSubmit(mobilefave);
            Favorite.SubmitChanges();

            Session["error_msg"] = "You have a new favorite";
            Response.Redirect("Favorite.aspx");
        }
    }
    #endregion


    protected void btn_delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid) // only valid page will proceed
        {
            DeleteFave();
        }
    }

    #region del fave
    protected void DeleteFave()
        {
            int iuser_id = Int32.Parse(Session["user_id"].ToString());
            using (FavoriteDataContext Favorite = new FavoriteDataContext())
            {
                try
                {
                    mobile_favorite fave = Favorite.mobile_favorites.Single(f => f.user_id == iuser_id);

                    Favorite.mobile_favorites.DeleteOnSubmit(fave);
                    Favorite.SubmitChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }
        }
    #endregion


    protected void GetFave()
    {
        using (FavoriteDataContext Favorite = new FavoriteDataContext())
        {
            var fave = from f in Favorite.mobile_favorites
                      // where f.user_id == Int32.Parse(Session["user_id"].ToString())
                       select f;

            ListFavorite.DataSource = fave;
            ListFavorite.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void GetRstr()
    {
        using (Restaurant2DataContext Restaurant2 = new Restaurant2DataContext())
        {
            var rstr = from r in Restaurant2.table_rests
                       select r;

            listSearch.DataSource = rstr;
            listSearch.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

mobile_rest is the table name

Comment: If you folks are going to down-vote the question within 5 minutes of its posting, at least explain why.

Comment: This question seems to be "I have an error! Look at my source code and make it work". Which part of the code do you think is problematic? What is your exact question?

Comment: The error message is complaining about the type "mobile_rest" yet you don't show its code.  Why not?

Comment: mobile_rest is the table name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "mobile_rest" is a database table name and you're using the standard VS2008 tools to create your LINQ-based classes, then I guess you've also got a partial class also named "mobile_rest."  Do you accidentally have this type declaring emptyChangingEventArgs in multiple places?  Just use the search functionality within VS and see how many times this static field is declared.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 or more emptyChangingEventArgs declared.  It's pretty obvious from the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error.
It happened bcoz i used d same table in more than 1 linq files.
So was clashing.
Thanks for taking d time out to reply though.